# How to deal with multiple objects in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

There are many examples for OpenGL ES 2 in how to visualize a single triangle or rectangle.

Google provides an [example for drawing shapes](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html) (triangles, rectangles) by creating a `Triangle` and `Rectangle` class which basically do all the opengl-stuff required for visualize these objects.

But what should you do, if you have more than one triangle? What if you have objects, consists of hundreds of triangles of different colors, different sizes and positions? I can't find any good tutorial for dealing with complex scenarios in opengl es.

---

### My approaches:

So I tried it out. First of all I've slightely changed the `Triangle`-Class to a more dynamic class (the constructor now gets the position and the color of the triangle). Basically this is "enough" for drawing complexe scenes. Every object would consist out of hundreds of these `Triangle`-classes and I render each of them seperately. But this consumes much computing power and I think most of the steps in the rendering process are redundant.

So I tried to "group" triangles into different categories. Now every object has his only vertexbuffer and puts every triangle at once in it. Now the performance is far better than before (where every triangle had his own buffer) but I still think, that it's not the correct way to go.

Is there any good example in the internet, where someone is drawing more than simple triangles or do you know where I can get these information from? I really like OpenGL but  it's pretty hard for beginners because of the lack of tutorials (for OpenGL ES 2 in Android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard representation of (triangle) meshes for rendering is using a vertex array containing all the vertices in the mesh, and an index array connecting storing the connectivity (triangles). You definitively want at most one draw call per object (but you might even be able to coalesce several objects).

Interleaved attribute arrays are the most efficient variant wrt. cache efficiency, so one Buffer object for the VA per object is enough. You might even combine several objects into one buffer object, even if you can not use a single draw call for both.

As GLES might be limited to 16 Bit indices, large models must be splitted into several "patches".